# Doesn't create save database

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I`m using monodroid and work with database via sqlite-net library. 
In one application transaction all data correctly putting and getting from database,
but when I deploy application next time my database file doesn't exists.

I`m using methods some like [these](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPro)

But I`m testing same code in MonoTouch and WP7 application and it`s allright.

So question is: why does database always lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To preserve data and cache data between application installs:

In Visual Studio:

```
Click Tools > Options...
In the left-hand tree, select Xamarin > Android Settings
In the right-hand panel, select [X] Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys.
```

In Xamarin Studio:

```
Click Tools > Options (Windows) or Xamarin Studio > Preferences (OS X)
In the left-hand tree, select Projects > Android
In the right-hand panel, select [X] Preserve data/cache between application deploys.
```

Based on the post [on Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/13869/)